# 2D barcode scanner for OS X?

Tags: barcode-scanner, qr-code

What is the best QR bar code scanner for OS X?

Comment: Hardware or software?

Comment: I'm not sure the people answering know what a 2d bar code is…

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the original questioner is asking, but I'm looking for an OS X application that will read QR-codes when photographed with the iSight camera built into laptops.

Answer (score 1):

**Software:**

[The barcode scanner project](http://www.bruji.com/cocoa/barcode.html), written in Cocoa, is for scanning barcodes on books, DVDs, CDs and video games as well as most other kind of EAN or UPC barcodes. It is part of our programs - DVDpedia, Bookpedia, CDpedia and Gamepedia - and is also used by Books. The code is available for free in the hopes that it'll be useful to other Mac developers. Of course it would be great if it were also improved with other developers' expertise and knowledge.

**[Hardware](http://www99.shopping.com/xPO-Metrologic-Instruments-Voyager-MK9540):**

[image]

Comment: Does it do 2d barcodes?

Answer (score 1):

I find this sdk for mac osx with buildin webcam

[Maybe this will help you](http://www.quickmark.com.tw/En/basic/downloadSDK.asp).

Answer (score 0):

All of the scanners from Intelliscanner (intelliscanner.com) work well with OS X as does the POS-X XI3000 (which seems to have been replaced by the XI3200 (http://www.pos-x.com/product-XI3200-31.aspx), which I have not used).

Note, when plugging one of these in sometimes the "Can't determine your keyboard…" window opens up. If that happens, just click the red dot to close the window as you should not need to (nor can you) use the keyboard setup to make them work.

(Sorry I couldn't make those URLs a link I got the "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink.")

Answer (score 0):

Most USB scanners are simply keyboard emulators. If OSX can take a standard USB keyboard then I'd imagine that it can take a standard USB barcode scanner such as the ones that Symbol do.